# cronjob runs with UTC timezone in AWS EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, timezone, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

I am running several cronjobs on kubernetes cluster and want them to run on EDT timezone America/New_York. I would like to find out, how to ensure that my jobs run at specific EDT time. At present, all these jobs run with UTC timezone.

- the POD images have been verified that they all have EDT timezone
- can set manually timezone by going to each host machine/container

There was some suggestion on finding kubernetes controller and setting timezone on that particular host/container. I would appreciate,if someone can shed light on

a. How one can find kubernetes admin controller?
b. How one can set timezone automatically on the container via command-line or yaml file

Comment: A feature request to [add timezone support to Kubernetes CronJobs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47202) was declined.

Comment: Timezone support has been added in Kubernetes 1.27 (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#time-zones).

Answer (score 5):

I came across following git repo and it helped me solve the problem

```
https://github.com/hiddeco/cronjobber
```

Overall, it allows one to set timezone along with cron job specification.